# Browser simulation android

Tags: java, android, browser, simulation

in my app I want to simulate a browser to work in the Background.
What I need is, that the app loads a page in the background fills in a field and clicks on a button.
I searched a little and found appium and selendroid. Now I am not sure if one of those can do what I want, as I want to put it in the Play Store and it seems like both need also a pc to work with.

Comment: It's not clear to me at all what you're trying to do.  What do you want do after the web page loads in the background?  What is the point of loading in the background?

Comment: The point is merging 2 search results of different pages into one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with a Webview and a Javascript bridge. Appium and Selendroid don't sound like a good match. Docs on integrating webviews here: http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

Answer (score 0):

y dont u just create an http request object in the app instead of loading a browser window in the background?

if all u need is to fill in fields and submit a form, assuming the form is the same every time and u know the api end point u want to hit, it can be easily achieved by simply building the http request in the app and sending it out without loading a url in a browser. Think of it like a post/get request from a rest client.

Let me know if u need more clarification.